# pager above reviews on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, pager, review

We are working on a website in magento 1.9 We have included the reviews directly on the product page, outside the tabs, by inserting

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?>
```

into view.phtml. This works fine however, the pager above the reviews is not being displayed. On the default review-page the pager is being displayed.

What is the reason that the pager is not displayed above the productreviews on the productpage and how can we fix this?

Regards,
Erik

Comment: Found a working solution at http://www.justonestepsolutions.net/2013/04/how-to-show-review-block-on-product-page-in-magento.html